# How to move from development to production

Tags: unit-test, production

Hi We have some development in our org. Now we want to move this development to production. How to do this, i bit confused in this. Can anyone tell how to move from development to production.
Thanks,
Regards,
Lavanya.

Comment: What are you confused about? Have you done any research on the available options?

Answer (score 4):

You have a few deployment options :

[Change Sets](https://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/changesets_about_outbound.htm)

[Force.com IDE Deployment](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Deploy_Force.com_Applications_Faster)

[Unmanaged Packages](https://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sharing_apps.htm)

[Force.com Migration Tool](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Migration_Tool_Guide)

Change Sets are the most straight forward but require some manual selection of resources to deploy. You might also find deployment via the Force.com IDE straight forward enough to do.

Unmanaged Packages and Migration tool would be slightly more 'sophisticated' and would find application in Enterprise Development / Deployment.

I should also add that any code needs a minimum of [75 % Test Coverage](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) to be able to move it to Production.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no general way to do that since shift into production really depends on kind of stuff your company had developed. I assume we are talking about software development for involving at least few other systems (because you didn't even mention that).

Basically if you have testing environment looking the same (which is a very good for almost any project) the shift should be relatively easy since everything should run without unexpected issues.

General advices:

1) every person involved (like admins/important users) should be informed in advance and (in case of admins) should agree on the schedule. also is really good if the system admins are on phone (in case something terrible happens)

2) if the shift means taking down some important system, do it during the night/weekend where "nobody" uses it

3) make backups of everything. something ban can always happen so you should have a complete rollback option

4) if deploying new application, make sure the users know about it and know how to use it (if this is the case they should use it right away after the app. comes into production)

5) make documentation of everything

But everything I have written is based on aforementioned assumption I made. If the assumption is not true, my reply doesn't help at all. :)