# Copy custom objects from developer to professional edition

Tags: migration-tool, professional-edition, developer-edition

We need to start a Salesforce project with a Professional Environment.
I thought to create a development environment to realize the custom objects, the visualforce pages and everything the customer needs. Then I want to copy this changes to the production environment.
As of we are in a Professional edition, we haven't access to change sets. Can I use the [Force.com Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm)? I cannot find if it's available in the professional edition. If it's not present, are there other alternatives?

PS: I've checked [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10489/how-to-move-from-development-to-production) question, but the answers propose solutions about the enterprise edition.

Comment: I've checked: migration tool isn't available on professional: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_tools_ant_using.htm&language=en_US